# Use vec4 color with vec2 texture coordinate

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have a Fragment Shader like this:

```
final String fragmentShader =
    "precision mediump float;" +
    "uniform sampler2D u_texture;" +
    "varying vec2 v_texCoord;" +
    "void main() {" +
    "   lowp vec4 textureColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord);" +
    "   gl_FragColor = textureColor;" +
    "}";
```

When drawing in GLSurfaceView, I will bind a texture into `u_texture`, and draw with texture coordinate `v_texCoord`.

But now I want to change to replace the texture with solid RGBA color. I use `uniform vec4 vColor;` to pass 4 floats directly as color.

I know there are a way to do it using:

```
"gl_FragColor = (vColor * texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord));"
```

But as I said above, I don't want to bind `sampler2D u_texture` any more, I just want to **fill it directly with solid color** AND FOLLOW the texture coordinate.

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't just use a 1x1 white texture? Or just another shader? "*AND FOLLOW the texture coordinate*" What does that mean? Solid colors don't "follow" anything.

Comment: *""AND FOLLOW the texture coordinate"* does int mean something like `gl_FragColor = vec4(vColor.rg * v_texCoord, vColor.ba);`?